# Get 100 Items from Azure Table Storage by known Keys result HTTP Error 414

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I want to show 100 items from Azure table, I already know PartitionKey and Rowkey, so for the $filter, something looks like this:

`((PartitionKey eq 'js32') and (RowKey eq '18371378441826619420')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js53') and (RowKey eq '18371389407961060290')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js37') and (RowKey eq '18371565010300884950')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js64') and (RowKey eq '18371570522532718663')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js78') and (RowKey eq '18371571234060779934')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js18') and (RowKey eq '18371620015195251645')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js59') and (RowKey eq '18371642621740783008')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js27') and (RowKey eq '18371653219702884172')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js79') and (RowKey eq '18371686842261536342')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js25') and (RowKey eq '18371703202567992223')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js25') and (RowKey eq '18371721921192859595')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js40') and (RowKey eq '18371723165056625088')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js58') and (RowKey eq '18371742515754080322')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js59') and (RowKey eq '18371742690277511383')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js27') and (RowKey eq '18371754349415311569')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js41') and (RowKey eq '18371755036440371353')) or ((PartitionKey eq 'js70') and (RowKey eq '18371790002968340255'))......`

`Total 100 items (so 100 PartitionKey and 100 RowKey)`

But then I got the error: `HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.`

Did you experience this error, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP response 414 is not specific to Windows Azure Table Storage: It simply means your request URI is too long. I've never run into this, as I typically don't build queries where multiple individual rows are called out in such a manner. I'm not sure what the max URI length is.

Having said that: This query doesn't look like it's going to be very efficient, as you're spanning partitions, meaning you'll be getting back partial results with continuation tokens (at least that's my guess based on the $filter fragment you presented). More info about continuation tokens and responses [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179421.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with David Makogon - you would be better off writing multiple queries. And if you do that, you can also use parallel threads to speed it all up. If you go this route, group on your partition key (each thread/connection hits a particular key/set of keys).

In terms of the long URIs, IE will support approx 2k. I don't know if this is an IE specific limit, or if this limit applies to the .NET WebClient as well. Also, be aware that even if it works with a very long query string, there might be proxies that won't work with that length of a Uri.

The other suggestion is to convert to range queries (greater than and less than), and exclude certain elements that you don't want with additional query fragments. This only works if your key structure is such that a range query makes sense.

Erick

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this via REST or the StorageClientLibrary?  The library does provide some nice abstractions for you.